# Word or phrase for departure/arrival (time + place)

Tags: single-word-requests

Perhaps this is a silly question, but is there a common word/phrase/term which would describe a time + location tuple (time and place), for flights or maritime links?

I.e. say I have a flight defined as:
Departure: Monday, 10:00 London,
Arrival: Monday, 18:00 New York.

`"Monday, 10:00"`/`"Monday, 18:00"` are both departure/arrival *times*, `"London"`/`"New York"` are both departure/arrival *ports* or *airports*.

So, is there a phrase which would describe both `"Monday, 10:00 London"` and `"Monday, 18:00 New York"`?

Goal would be to be able to describe it as:

- a *route* contains one or more *connections*
- a *connection* has a single departure *"?"* and arrival *"?"*
- a *"?"* is defined by a timestamp and airport

If there are any better terms for what I am describing above, I'd be grateful to hear them also.

Comment: Wouldn't you want three elements: *time*, *place* and *direction* (inbound or outbound)?

Comment: @JHCL: that would be an option too, yes, but not so important.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be "departure" or "arrival" ? Those describe the time and place of a departure/arrival?

Comment: You're looking for a word that pins down a specific location in time and space then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest ***juncture***. I used it in context of modelling a software system for the term described in the question.

It is defined as a *point in time* and also as a *place* where things join.

See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/juncture

Answer (score 1):

You should check ***coordinates***. Though the definition mentions space, you can add date+time as an additional coordinate (refer to the *time coordinate* example from ODO below).

M-W:

> **[coordinate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coordinate)**
>   *noun*
>   **1 a** :  any of a set of numbers used in specifying the location of a point on a line, on a surface, or in space
>   **b** :  any one of a set of variables used in specifying the state of a substance or the motion of a particle or momentum

ODO:

> **[coordinate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coordinate)** (also co-ordinate)
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** Each of a group of numbers used to indicate the position of a point, line, or plane.
>
> ‘These were Newton's words when he used time as an important
>   coordinate in the laws of mechanics that he described so accurately.’
>
> ‘The address becomes much more like a Social Security number than a
>   street coordinate.’

Comment: Specifically, [space-time coordinates](http://www.whoniverse.net/tardis/navigationslidecontrols).

Answer (score 0):

You maybe referring to a flight leg or a flight segment. But that term does not necessarily include the time aspect.

Comment: A segment would be an interval from point A to B, but I am interested in how to call these points (including time).

Comment: Would a "stop" make sense? As in: "this route has 3 stops"? It indicates the number of "hops", but I am not sure if it would make sense to say "a connection has a single departure stop and an arrival stop"?

Comment: There may be a more technical term but on our team we would already understand if we say Departure Information and Arrival Information. Sorry it may not be of much help. :)

Comment: Yes a stop makes sense as well but it may not necessarily include the time aspect.

Answer (score 0):

How about *itinerary*?

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/itinerary):

> An *itinerary* is your travel plan — where you will go and when you will
>   be there. If you make plans to fly to Paris from Beijing or take a
>   train to Chicago from Mexico City, you will need an itinerary. That
>   means you will have a plan that displays how you will get from point
>   to point in your travels and when you will be at each point. This word
>   comes from the Middle English itinerarius and is defined as being
>   "about a journey." Itineraries can be really useful because if you
>   give your mother yours, she will always know where you are!